# Ontology creation from structured text

Tags: owl, ontology

I have a structured text file with keywords structured like this:

```
    abc
        asd
    asdf 
        asdfdg
    def
    asdfads
```

Now, I want to create an OWL ontology using this data. Basically, the terms are classes and the terms within the indent are sub classes.

I've looked at python packages like [RDFLib](https://github.com/RDFLib/rdflib) and [Protege](https://protege.stanford.edu/) to import the file and create an ontology, albeit with little success.

What is the best way to create an ontology from structured data like this?

Comment: if there are only classes and subclasses in that file, the "best way" is reading line by line and put results to the ontology object. With Java NIO2 it is almost one line of code. Don't know exactly, but sure that in python it must be even easier.

Comment: Or "convert" it to CSV and use some CSV to OWL converter. But I'd also go for small Java or Python script - it's almost trivial for building a class hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

Having failed using RDFLib and Protege, maybe try http://seth-scripting.sourceforge.net/ (given the project is dead, I'd invest a little more time looking at RDFLib or Protege)

"Best" way isn't something anyone can really answer.